# Rooting Panasonic Eluga Pulse X phone

Tags: rooting

I just recently bought an Android phone named Panasonic Eluga Pulse X, but its internal storage is way too low that I want to remove some bloatware by gaining root access.

I have tried so many one-click root apps like Framaroot, KingoRoot, etc. but none worked.

How to root this device?

Comment: Isn't it possible to unlock bootloader and flash custom recovery? One click methods aren't a genuine way to root phone.

Comment: @Irfan Latif unlocking bootloader and installing twrp is possible but first i should get the scatter files which i am not able to get because mtk droid tools doesn't support mt6737 chipset